# Calling an Get API with HTTP Header and Body with Alamofire swift3

Tags: json, swift3, header, alamofire

I'm trying to recreate GET request that already works in Postman in Swift 3 with Alamofire 4, but i'm always getting a Status Code 400 "Bad Request". I am out of ideas about what I'm doing wrong here.

This is the request in Postman, additionally there is a username and password in the Body in JSON format: 
[image]

also i find out data array latitude and longtitute data and save my global variable. Any body help me this out. Thanks Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
    let url = "http://example.com?userid=XXX"
    let params: [String: Any] = [ 
                                    "username": "YOUR_USERNAME",
                                    "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD"
                                ]


    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "token": "YOUR_TOKEN_HERE",
        "x-api-key": "YOUR_KEY_HERE"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            debugPrint(JSON)
            //parse your response here

        case .failure(let error):
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is Get API responce why you use parameters here, please share me proper code with my "data" array dictionary data @rami

Comment: @mikekumawat as you mentioned "additionally there is a username and password in the Body in JSON format", this is done by sending parameters as dictionary with "JSONEncoding.default" encoding method. I'm not sure what you mean by "my "data" array dictionary"